# codenvy gdb debugger for go

Tags: go, gdb, codenvy

I got at reply from Codenvy that gdb debugging go(lang)is working, but no documentations on how to - and I can not find any documentations on this. I got this [link](https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/debug#gdb) from Codenvy.

The Codenvy docs do not describe how, just that it can.

Can you, and if so please provide the steps - just for the web-go-simple app?

I just want to verify myself that it works with the sample app template "web-go-simple" before moving.

Notes: Compiling with: `go build -ldflags "-w"` and not -g for Java as the doc says.

Also the GOPATH is `/go` and the run command is `cd /projects/web-go-simple && go get -d && go run -g main.go`. I might be that they have set it up without `go install` or `"go build"`.

Comment: Is there a code sample you try to debug? On their website it states like       > GDB does not understand Go programs well. Link [here](https://golang.org/doc/gdb)

Comment: Yes, it is the template for go. It is called "web-go-simple" and it runs fine - but no debugging. The strange thing is that I have emailed with a CEO from Codenvy and he tells me that it works - but he don't have time to write down the steps? Hmm